# Error in if (download_method_secure()) from installing native R kernel for Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-irkernel

I tried to install [R Kernel](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/) to my Jupyter notebook on Windows from

```
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
```

but I ran into this error

```
Error in if (download_method_secure()) { :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This issue came up for me when I was relying on the default `r-essentials` version of devtools instead of the newest version.  After I did a `conda install -f -c r r-devtools` and got the newest version, the error went away.  YMMV of course.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, but thank you for your YMMV notice :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when dealing with conda and devtools. In order to figure it out I looked at the [download_method](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/download-method.R) function in devtools, which is throwing the error. The solution for me was to set the global options in R for `download.file.method`. It seems the issue is really with Devtools trying unsuccessfully to download from a secure site.

On windows, this line fixed the problem: `options(download.file.method = "wininet")`

For Mac/Linux, the line would be `options(download.file.method = "libcurl")`

I found these lines on this page. There are some other options as well, for older versions of R.
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827897-Secure-Package-Downloads-for-R